# Jquery base64 encoding with special characters

Tags: php, jquery, base64, special-characters

I have an app with an input field where you input your name. The app outputs the name on a pdf document with FPDF. As this app is in swedish, many people will input names with special character like å, ä, ö. One of the inputs (the name of a person) looks like this:

```
fromName = $.base64.encode($('#voucherName').val())
```

This goes through:

```
$.ajax({
    url: frontend_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data: 'action=wpgv_doajax_pdf_save_func&nonce='+nonce+'&template='+templates_id+'&for='+forName+'&from='+fromName+'&value='+voucherValue+'&message='+message+'&expiry='+expiry+'&code='+code+'&firstname='+firstName+'&lastname='+lastName+'&email='+email+'&address='+address+'&pincode='+pincode+'&paymentmethod='+paymentMethod,
    success: function(a) {
        window.location.replace(a);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
});
```

This is then decoded in php like this:

```
$from = sanitize_text_field(base64_decode($_POST['from']));
```

But the problem is that when someone for example enters the name Björn, the special character "ö" i is displayed in weird trash characters.

Comment: Why using base64 to begin with? HTTP is able to transport any unicode character, given the transfer-encoding is correct.

Comment: I did not make the app. I just customize it to fit my needs. I don't know why the author uses base64. What are standard reasons to use it? Security? Do you think that I can remove it?

Comment: The usual reason is if you want to transfer binary data without using a standard file upload.